# InverseFourierSequenceTransform gives zero

Tags: fourier-analysis

I am wondering why Mathematica(12) in the following code

```
InverseFourierSequenceTransform[1,kx,x]
```

gives different results if we just change "1" to "1."

```
InverseFourierSequenceTransform[1.,kx,x]
```

******* Update *******

For better understanding, let review the followings

```
InverseFourierSequenceTransform[1, kx, x]
InverseFourierSequenceTransform[1., kx, x]
InverseFourierSequenceTransform[1. + a Cos[kx], kx, x] /. {a -> 0}
```

where gives,

```
DiscreteDelta[x]
0.
Piecewise[{{1., x == 0}}, 0.]
```

Comment: In the second expression, `x` is an approximate number and it cannot be **exactly** zero. If it is not **exactly** zero then `DiscreteDelta[x]` is `0.` as indicated.

Comment: I think this "1"  or "1." should come before  DiscreteDelta[x]. Please find the update @BobHanlon